# Information extraction from Twitter JSON Feed

Tags: java, python, json, twitter

I have a huge(in GB's) twitter data feed in JSON format to be analysed.Each tweet is represented as one json object.I need to do few analysis on this data like

a: Extract conversations from these feeds.
b: Finding statistics

Sample Format of the record 
https://gist.github.com/hrp/900964

1.Please suggest the general approch to extract the required information.
2.The best language to be used(Java or any other)
3.Overview of process if it to be done in java (like file handling and so on)
4.Any useful reference link relevent to this problem.

Note : Data consists of millions of JSON objects.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion the best language to run an analysis of your data is R. In your case, you have already the twitter data but in case you want to query twitter data, you can use R packages that are ready to be used and very convenient:

-twitteR: You connect to the Twitter API and you can do queries  http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/twitteR/index.html

-streamR: It connects to the Twitter Streaming API to get tweets in real time http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/streamR/index.html

Then just google about how to Mine Twitter data with R and there are MANY articles, with good methods about how to do that, create nice visualizations, etc that will give you very good insights. There are most of them based in a package called "tm" which is the Text Mining most popular package for R: 
http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tm/index.html

Here you have a couple interesting links to get started:

http://www.r-bloggers.com/analyze-twitter-data-using-r/

http://www.rdatamining.com/examples/text-mining

hope it helps!

Comment: I have used the java with GSON as the data is not huge. Will check about R next time!!! Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Big Insights. Lots of documentation and examples readily available to get you started. It is an analytics platform precisely to address huge data

http://www-01.ibm.com/software/data/infosphere/biginsights/